# why case sensitive doesn't work in elasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, case-sensitive, elasticsearch-query

I want to using case sensitive in Elasticsearch `query_string`

```
query_string: {
      default_field : 'message',
      query: 'info',
    }
```

If I enter `info`, the output be displayed `info` as well as `INFO`.

How to use case sensitive in Elasticsearch `query_string`?

Comment: Can you show the mapping of the `message` field?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at my answer? let me know if you need more clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query strings are not discouraged for search bar or normal full-text searches as mentioned in [official ES doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html). From the same link:

> Because it returns an error for any invalid syntax, we don’t recommend
>   using the query_string query for search boxes.
>
> If you don’t need to support a query syntax, consider using the match
>   query. If you need the features of query syntax, use the
>   simple_query_string query, which is less strict.

I would suggest, using the `match` query as recommended above, Which is analyzed and provides case insensitive search on text fields. So in your example you can define mapping as below:

```
"mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "message": {
                "type": "text" --> note `text` type which uses `standard` analyzer
            }
        }
    }
```

### Index sample data(Notice case sensitive docs)

```
{
    "message": "foo"
}
{
    "message": "Foo"
}
{
    "message": "FOO"
}
```

And then use the below query to query data:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "message": "foo" -->you can change it to `Foo` and it will still give all results.
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And it gives all the results as shown below:

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "querystring",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.13353139,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "FOO"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "querystring",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.13353139,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "Foo"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "querystring",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 0.13353139,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "foo"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: thank you. Are you said I should change 'mapping property message type', right?

Comment: @tail, yes and then use the query which I provided in my answer :-)

Comment: And. I am using regular expression in query_string. Can I also apply what you said in this case? I don't know that where I setting the 'mapping message type'.

Comment: @tail. `message` is the field in your elasticsearch index and In mapping, I am defining this as `text` field, so the default analyzer is applied on. them, which included `lowercase` token fiter and match query as mentioned in my answer is also anlyzerd and converts all text to lowercase. hence it provides case-insensitive search

Comment: @tail, just created some sample index, with my mapping and index data , given by me, you can change the value of `message` field to `info` or `INFO` as its there in your qustion and search on them and you would get your expected result :-)

Comment: Thank you. umm... So If I send 'mapping: {properties: {}}, query:{bool:{must:[]}} ' to searchAPI, Can I receive result? I tried but I couldn't receive result. How to change the 'mapping'? I sorry I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

It all about your template and what is your field type and if it analyzed.
you can check below for more details:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/is-elasticsearch-querying-on-a-field-value-case-sensitive/74005

Answer (score 0):

You could try using field 'message.keyword' if your mapping has set 'message' as an analyzed field. It will result in a case sensitive search.

Comment: 'message.keyword' instead of 'message'? I tried it but 'searchAPI' can't find the keyword.

Comment: Can you share your mapping for the field 'message'? - @tail

Comment: umm.. I want to share my 'message' field mapping. but I doesn't touch my mapping field. so I don't know where my mapping filed. Perhaps, Is the 'mapping field' a backend?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html - @tail